# IEnumerable<string> checkboxes get old date

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

my code is :

```
IEnumerable<string> checkboxes
```

checkboxes contains data :

```
<"4,12/16/2014 00:00:00">
<"8,11/16/2014 00:00:00">
<"6,10/16/2014 00:00:00">
```

4,8,6 are FileId

i need to get the fileId of oldDate from checkboxes list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var allIds = checkboxes.Select(x=>int.Parse(x.Split(new []{','})[0]));
```

if you want the oldest

```
int.Parse((checkboxes.OrderBy(x => DateTime.Parse(x.Split(new[] {','})[1])).First()).Split(new[] {','})[0]);
```

both cases will fail if checkboxes is empty. Please validate first and check the parsing of the date, you may have to pass a proper formater